# What do the allegiance options do?

Tags: trombone-champ

In the settings for Trombone Champ there's an Allegiance section with options for Baboon Quantity (Normal, Most, Inferno (Mostest)) and Baboon Preference (None, Mandril, Hamadryas, All of Them).

What do these Allegiance options do?

[image: Allegiance options]